# Angular 5 StaticInjectorError while registering service

Tags: angular, service, dependency-injection

Here is my problem.

I have a valid Component that relies on `RestapiService`.
So my constructor looks like:

```
  constructor(private store: Store<fromPlotData.PlotDataState>, private rest: RestapiService) {
      this.parseData();
      store.select('plotData').subscribe(v => this.subscribeOnStore(v));
   }
```

Nothing fancy there. It doesn't show me an error.

In my `app.module.ts` file, I import this file like:

`import { RestapiService } from './components/services/restapi.service';`

And my `@NgModule` decorator looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SpinnerComponent,
    FullComponent,
    NavigationComponent,
    BreadcrumbComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    SetupviewComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot(Approutes, { useHash: false }),
    PerfectScrollbarModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      name: 'NgRx Book Store DevTools'
    }),
    TabsComponentsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    RestapiService, <--- This should obviously work
      {
      provide: PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG,
      useValue: DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG
    }, {
    provide: LocationStrategy,
    useClass: HashLocationStrategy
  },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My service looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  header: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type' : 'application/json'})
};
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8000';


@Injectable()
export class RestapiService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }


  getAxesParameter(id: number) {
    return this.http.get(API_URL + '/get_axes_parameter/' + id);
  }
   ................ Here goes 50 more API calls ...................

} // end of class
```

However, I'm constantly getting a StaticInjectorError.

I have tried removing `node_modules`, and installing everything from scratch, and running it multiple times, but no success.

[image: Static injector error]

Answer (score 0):

It was just a wrong relative path to the service in my component.